# How to solve erroe 428C9 in ASP.NET Core MVC?

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, crud

I made a new function for my website.It can do the job like **save as**.
And it can work will.
But when I create a new project, it suddenly can't work,and show the error 428C9.
What should I do? Can someone give me advice?
It is .cshtml

```
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xl-10">
        <form asp-action="Saveas">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="IpAddress" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="IpAddress" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="IpAddress" class="text-danger"></span>

            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Protocol" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Protocol" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Protocol" class="text-danger"></span>

            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="ToolHostPort" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="ToolHostPort" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="ToolHostPort" class="text-danger"></span>

            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="ToolSvid" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="ToolSvid" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="ToolSvid" class="text-danger"></span>

            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Pid" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Pid" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Pid" class="text-danger"></span>

            </div>
            <input type="hidden" asp-for="Pid" />
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<div>
    <a asp-action="Index">Back to List</a>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
}
```

It is controller

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> Saveas(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        var gatewaySettingCloud = await _context.GatewaySettingClouds.FindAsync(id);
        if (gatewaySettingCloud == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        return View(gatewaySettingCloud);
    }


    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Saveas([Bind("Ipaddress,Protocol,Toolhostport,Toolsvid,Pid")] GatewaySettingCloud gatewaySettingCloud)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            _context.Add(gatewaySettingCloud);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }
        return View(gatewaySettingCloud);
    }
```

Comment: First of all you need to debug to see where the error occurs. Most likely this will be at `await _context.SaveChangesAsync()` since this seems like a postgres error but you should make sure. Then you might need to look into your database setup/models to make sure that you generate proper ids for when saving a new entity.

Comment: I agree with Karl-Johan, the error code indicates that the issue comes from sql command executing. I'm afraid that to solve your issue, you need to check the input parameters suitable for the columns in your table.

Comment: @Karl-JohanSjögren OK,I will check it.

Comment: @TinyWang Yes. I think so too.But I didn't find any wrong.It is so sad....

Comment: @Haohao1198 Thanks for your response and I think you can also use the data to insert into the database directly to check it.

Comment: @TinyWang Yes.I have try to insert into the database with my "create" function, and it can work will. Most important thing is I have two project, and I use same code ,one can work other can't work.....

Comment: hey, I have just solve the problem.Sorry for my careless. Although my database's cloum is same, but the properties is different . One of them use 「user identity always column() 」......

Comment: @Karl-JohanSjögren You are right. Thanks!!

Comment: @Haohao1198 I'm glad to see it's solved and could you pls post your finding as the answer to end this case? And thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find  the database does not accept  from applications, so I create a new column replace original column which one can't accept data  from applications.Then  I can insert the data successful!!
Helper:Karl-Johan Sjögren、Tiny Wang